# What's the difference between "$^N" and "$+"?

Tags: regex, perl, variables

Can someone show me an example which demonstrates the different behavior of these two variables ( $^N and $+ )?

Comment: Is this homework? Or did you just wake up in the middle of the night going "oh no! how is $^N different from $+? Now I cannot sleep!"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> **`$+`**:      The text matched by the last bracket of the last successful
>            search pattern.

versus

> **`$^N`**:    The text matched by the used group most-recently closed (i.e.
>           the group with the rightmost closing parenthesis) of the last
>           successful search pattern.

This should illustrate the difference:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my $s = '12345';

if ( $s =~ /(1([0-9]))/ ) {
    print "$_\n" for $+, $^N;
}
```

Output:

```
2
12
```